# Implicit declaration of function 'if' is invalid in C99?

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to make a register page for my app and when I was making my 'if' statement, I got a C99 error. I am using xCode 5.1.1, and I was using a parse SDK and frame work. I am not exactly sure what I did wrong, but if it's a very obvious mistake I apologize.  :

```
- (IBAction)continueAction:(id)sender {
    [_usernameField resignFirstResponder];
    [_emailField resignFirstResponder];
    [_passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    [_retypeField resignFirstResponder];
    [self checkFieldsComplete];
}

- (void) checkFieldsComplete {
    If ([_usernameField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_emailField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_retypeField.text isEqualToString:@""]); { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woaaahhhh, hold on there" message:@"You must complete all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
     {
        [self checkPasswordsMatch];
    }

}

- (void) checkPasswordsMatch {
    if (![_passwordField.text isEqualToString:_retypeField.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woaaahhhh" message:@"Passwords don't match" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        [self registerNewUser];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
If ([_usernameField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_emailField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_retypeField.text isEqualToString:@""]); { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woaaahhhh, hold on there" message:@"You must complete all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Rename `If` to `if`. C keywords and identifiers are case-sensitive. Also, remove the semi-colon after the if statement. You will also need to insert `else` if you want the second block to execute if the if-statement is false. Overall, it should look like this:

```
if ([_usernameField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_emailField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_retypeField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woaaahhhh, hold on there" message:@"You must complete all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    [self checkPasswordsMatch];
}
```

Comment: thank you! I knew it was such an obvious error. I guess I need to pay better attention